# Error Occuring while using ON/OFF switche in android

Tags: android, android-layout, switch-statement

I want a On/Off switch [Mentioned here](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/switches.html) in my application. But my layout is getting error while design for switch as given below 
     `<Switch
        android:textOn="ON"
        android:textOff="OFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>`

The error i am getting is

```
`ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2012-07-12 16:33:07.619
!MESSAGE main.xml: Failed to find style 'switchStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2012-07-12 16:33:07.620
!MESSAGE main.xml: Failed to find style 'switchStyle' in current theme

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2012-07-12 16:33:07.620
!MESSAGE main.xml: Failed to find style 'switchStyle' in current theme


!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2012-07-12 16:33:07.621

!MESSAGE main.xml: Failed to find style 'switchStyle' in current theme


!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2012-07-12 16:33:07.622

!MESSAGE main.xml: Failed to find style 'switchStyle' in current theme


!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2012-07-12 16:33:07.622

!MESSAGE main.xml: Failed to find style 'switchStyle' in current theme


!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 2 0 2012-07-12 16:33:07.637

!MESSAGE main.xml: You must supply a layout_width attribute.


!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 2 0 2012-07-12 16:33:07.638

!MESSAGE main.xml: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
```

my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<Switch
    android:textOn="ON"
    android:textOff="OFF"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please attach the code of your xml file ?

Comment: Its having only one component that is switch

Comment: @Paru : try after setting `@android:style/Theme.Holo` theme for Application and also see this issue http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21017

Comment: style="@android:style/Theme.Holo" added in the layout. But not worked

Answer (score 0):

Switch widget was added in api level 14.
Make sure you set android:minSdkVersion="14" in AndroidManifest.xml